# How do multiple OR's || work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
     if(eggsAmount < eggsMin || milkAmount < milkMin || flourAmount || FlourMin)
```

Does it mean whichever of these are true?

Comment: That's generally what OR means, yes.  If I said "get me eggs, or milk, or cheese", would getting any of these things fulfill my request?

Comment: It means if *"any"* of them are true. I'm not sure what you mean by "whichever" in this context. You can use `||` as a "falsy coalesce", but wrapped in an `if ( ... )`, you'll only know whether *at least one* was true or not.

Comment: Semantically, it means "if any of these are truthy, then the result is truthy". In terms of implementation, though, it will go through the list of terms from left to right, and as soon as it finds one that is truthy, it will return that term's value as-is.

Comment: Also, you may want to specify what you believe this condition is. Some newer developers often think that `milkAmount < milkMin || flourAmount || FlourMin` means *"Milk Amount is less than milkMin, or it's less than flourAmount, or it's less than flourMin"*. This is **not the case**. You have to explicitly do `milkAmount < milkMin || milkAmount <  flourAmount || milkAmount < FlourMin` if that's the case you're after. Though, not clear if you are.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk Close - it returns the result of the last expression evaluated. `1 + 1 || 1 + 3` returns `2` whereas `1 + 1 && 1 + 3` returns `4`. If the expression is a value itself, say `a = 123 ... a || b`, you get that value as-is since it's the result of the condition's expression.

Comment: @JaredFarrish The question was asking about `or`, not `and` :) In the case of `or`, returning the result of the last expression evaluated is equivalent to returning the first truthy value :)

Comment: @IceMetalPunk The difference is when they're all falsey. It returns the last expression's value.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk It doesn't return the value as-is unless it is a value from an expression, e.g. the condition evaluates as a value itself. Full stop. The inclusion of the second condition was to illustrate this further. Your choice.

Comment: @Barmar Ah! You're correct, I overlooked that edge case.

Comment: I went in some sort of panic and deleted my answer, basically stating that the expression is globally evaluated as true is any of the conditions is true. But now I'm not sure why this statement was wrong even after consulting https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp . Could anybody provide a source in which I can understand?

Comment: @Cubo78 Open the console and enter `1 + 2 || 3 + 4 || 5 + 6`. You get `3` not `true`. This is a really interesting feature, functionally.

Comment: And compare to PHP: https://3v4l.org/l9VBj

Comment: Oh, ok. But within an if it makes the condition true, does not? I always used it for logic evaluation in my (amateur-ish) applications and not for strange C-like assignements.

Comment: @Cubo78 `if` only evaluates if the result is truthy.

Comment: @JaredFarrish that was the OP was asking about. Anyway thanks to you I learned something new. Maybe with some edits I can salvage my answer. Ps: btw, this question  (though is really basic) is not a 100% dupe of the linked question, because in that case the OP had wrongly used || instead of &&.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in an if statement with only OR `||` operators, it will simply go through each condition and as soon as it finds one that is true, the `if` statement resolves as true, the rest are not checked, and the code in the `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

An *if statement* containing multiple **OR** conditions (`||`) has in Javascript the same behaviour descripted by Boolean Algebra: the whole evaluation is `True` if *any* of the conditions is true.

At this [w3schools link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) you can find JS logic operators description.

Anyway the evaluation of the expression itself is not necessarily a boolean value. The expression

```
Res = expr1 || expr2 || ... || exprN
```

is evaluated as the first condition that can be evaluated as true (for example if `expr1` is `4+7`, `Res=11`.

If none of the condition can be evaluated as true the assigned value is the value contained in the last condition: `Res = exprN`.

*(thanks to Jared Farrish, Barmar and Teemu*)